# Command failing when running through Teamcity Commandline option

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command, teamcity

I have a batch script which I am triggering through teamcity.

[image]

The batch script has a step to run a `Powershell` command to get a file name.

```
set "psCommand=powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.json -Name)""
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%psCommand%') do set "leaf=%%I"
echo file name is %leaf%
```

When I run this batch script from normal command prompt, it is executed correctly and prints

```
file name is MyFile.json
```

However, when Teamcity executes the same file, I get a failure:

```
[15:18:46] :     [Step 1/1] C:\BuildAgent\work\6111111111111111>  set "psCommand=powershell -command "(Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.json -Name)""
[15:18:46]W:     [Step 1/1] "" was unexpected at this time.
[15:18:46]W:     [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 255
[15:18:46]E:     [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 255 (Step: Build using command line (Command Line))
[15:18:46]E:     [Step 1/1] Step Build using command line (Command Line) failed
```

What am I missing? How can I make this work?

---

As per suggestion in comment, I tried this as well:

```
for %%I in (C:\Temp\*.json) do set "leaf=%%~nxI"
echo file name is %leaf%
somecommand --fileName %leaf%
```

When running in command line, it executes successfully:

```
file name is MyFile.json
```

But when running through Teamcity, I get:

```
20:51:19  C:\BuildAgent\work\681e991514b6f045>set "leaf=MyFile.json"
20:51:19  file name is
```

Why is file name not getting printed on the `echo` statement?

Now reading this: **https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html**

Comment: I guess there is some sort of escaping necessary for the quotation marks…

Comment: I have to ask why? especially when `for %%I in (C:\Temp\*.json) do set "leaf=%%~nxI"` does it more simply. It requires no unnecessary variable to be defined, is shorter, quicker, and benefits from not having to run any external utilities from the batch file.

Comment: @Compo: Thanks for that. But Teamcity is still not able to resolve the file name. I have updated the question with your command.

Comment: So is that all the code or is this snippet of code sitting inside a parenthesized block of code which will require delayed expansion. Why can't you condense the code to this: `for %%I in (C:\Temp\*.json) do somecommand --fileName %%~nxI`

Comment: I was under the impression that using the Command Line option each of your individual lines would be written to a new .cmd file and then run. Also TeamCity treats a string surrounded by percentage signs `%` in the script as a parameter reference. To prevent TeamCity from treating the text in the percentage signs as a property reference, you'd need to use double percentage signs to escape them. That may mean that your variables would need modification, e.g. `%%leaf%%`, and if you stick with your powershell version, `%%psCommand%%`.